# Use simulate dates for today in Fluid

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x

TYPO3 has the nice "simulate date" option in the admin panel.

But this doesn't propagate to fluid as in

```
{f:format.date(date: 'today' format: 'Y-m-d')}
```

Apparently, this is php at work, not the TYPO3 API.

Is there a simple possibility to simulate a virtual "today" date and pass it to fluid?

Comment: the simulated time is a PHP variable which gets set on page generation, so you have aconsistent timestamp for your rendering (otherwise different time calculations could work with different timestamps, which might result even in different dates when the page call is milliseconds before midnight). I don't know wether this PHP-variabel is accessably by typoscript. probable not by fluid. in worst case you can write a tiny PHP-viewhelper which returns this global varibale.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use a typoscript condition to declare a setting.

```
[yourcondition]
    plugin.tx_your_ext.settings.dateOverride = 2017-11-11 11:11:11
[global]
```

Then make sure the settings are passed to the view. You can do that in your controller action

```
$this->view->assign('settings', $this->settings);
```

And then pass the value to the viewhelper. You can use any value, that can be interpreted by the DateTime constructor.

```
{f:format.date(date: settings.dateOverride format: 'Y-m-d')}
```

A list of possible typoscript conditions:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html

If you need the date to be set more dynamically, you can use a url parameter and request your page like:

yourpage.com/path/to/your/site?no_cache=1&spoofedDate=2017-11-11T11:11:11Z

I guess you can utilize the DataSubmissionHook to set the value if the simulated date feature of typo3 is used. Maybe that gives you the most comfort.

To access request params in your Controller:

```
$this->request->getArgument()
```

Or

```
GeneralUtility::_GET()
```

A fancy way of solving that is to overload the DateTime object, so it respects the simulated date Feature.

Answer (score 0):

You could use install the [PHP timecop extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/timecop) and set the date initially in `index.php`.

Alternatively, open a feature request to fluid to support the simulated time.